# Python import module with alias

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python 3 and currently learning how to create Python modules. I have created below package structure.

```
maindir
    test.py
    package
        __init__.py
        subpackage
            __init__.py
            module.py
```

This is my module.py file

```
name="John"
age=21
```

and this is my test.py file

```
import package.subpackage.module
print(module.name)
```

When I run test.py I am getting this error `NameError: name 'module' is not defined`
However, when I change the import statement to `import package.subpackage.module as mymod` and print the name with `print(mymod.name)` then its working as expected. Its printing name John.
I didn't understand why its working with second case and not with first.

Comment: Use `print(package.subpackage.module.name)`. `module` alone is not in the current scope.

Comment: Then how `import sys` `print(sys.path)` works?

Comment: @vivekratnaparkhi that is because `sys` is an imported name. when you import `package.subpackage.module`, you import the name `package.subpackage.module`, not `module`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you were attempting was this:

```
from package.subpackage import module
```

Then you can reference `module` as a name afterwards.

If you do:

```
import package.subpackage.module
```

Then your module will be called exactly `package.subpackage.module`.

Comment: I want to understand the behaviour of this style of import `import package.subpackage.module`. I still understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

With little bit of reading I understood this behaviour now. Please correct me If I am wrong.

With this `import package.subpackage.module` style of import statement you have to access the objects with their fully qualified names. For example, in this case
`print(package.subpackage.module.name)`

With aliasing I can shorten the long name with `import package.subpackage.module as mymod` and print directly with `print(mymod.name)`

In short `print(package.subpackage.module.name)` == `print(mymod.name)`

Comment: you can also import the short name as above: `from package.subpackage import module` then `print(module.name)`